# How stellar prevent DDoS

Tags: horizon, server, rate-limiting

How stellar prevent DDoS attack from rest API (https://horizon.stellar.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Horizon, there is a "**rate limit**" variable, which ensures no more than N requests from same IP in one hour.

> X-RateLimit-Limit --- The maximum number of requests that the current client can make in one hour.
>   X-RateLimit-Reset ---   Seconds until a new window starts.
>   https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/rate-limiting.html

---

Note that Horizon is just an entry point to the Stellar blockchain network.

On the wider perspective of the underlying Stellar blockchain, the small **transaction fee** could somehow deter extensive gabrage dump into the network.

The fee is small enough to be ignored by normal users, as each operation costs a fee of 0.00001 XLM [(around 0.0001115 USD)](https://currencio.co/xlm/usd/0.00001/). For intended DDoS attackers, ENORMOUS multiple of 0.00001 XLM will be charged.

---

*That said, if you have the money to burn, you could DDoS the public network.*

---

---

p.s.

The current values at the public Horizon are

```
x-ratelimit-limit: 101
x-ratelimit-reset: 1
```

which means "maximum of 101 requests" in "every 1 second".